# Does giving rations count towards your "recovery items used" in Metal Gear Solid 4

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

In Metal Gear Solid 4, you can walk up to militia or PMC troops and give them items, including rations. Does doing so count towards your tally of "recovery items used" or not?

Comment: I don't really know. But some FAQs say "consumed" rather than "used", suggesting that giving rations away doesn't count. See the "Pig" emblem on the IGN guide: http://au.guides.ign.com/guides/714044/page_6.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't count.  The only items which count against you are Rations, Noodles and Regain. (Which are used on yourself.)  Syringe does not count, and anything that just recovers psyche does not count.

Note: You have to be really careful when doing this challenge because sometimes you will automatically munch a ration when taking damage.  I would recommend that you drop them all to be safe :).